# Place a view at the end of multiline TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

I want to add a custom view (a view with both text and icon) at the end of dynamic `TextView` like in this picture.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you have done?

Answer (score 8):

It is possible programmatically:

```
fun TextView.setIconifiedText(text: String, @DrawableRes iconResId: Int) {
    SpannableStringBuilder("$text#").apply {
        setSpan(
            ImageSpan(context, iconResId, DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM),
            text.length,
            text.length + 1,
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
    }.let {
        setText(it)
    }
}
```

```
textView.setIconifiedText(
    "First line text that is longer.\nSecond line text.",
    R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp
)
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you for answering, actually I want to add a custom view at the end of my TextView

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `android:drawableEnd`

Comment: It doesn't work if I want to add a custom view at the end

Answer (score -3):

Place both of them in relative layout and add this

```
android:layout_toEndOf="<id of first view>"
```

to the custom view